# windows hotkey combination to start the browser?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, hotkeys

Is there a win hotkey combination to start your browser? I know that win + E will start windows explorer, but I have found nothing to start the browser in windows 7?

If there isn't such a key is there a utility that could be installed to set up the combination like Win+B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some keyboards have special keys that open a browser, probably using special HID keycodes or application software. You could also try setting up a [shortcut key](http://www.thetechfaq.com/2008/03/30/how-to-create-an-application-shortcut-key/) or use [another method](https://superuser.com/questions/110397/reliable-custom-windows-shortcut-keys) for launching the program.

Comment: Site ahend contains malware (the first link for shortcut key)

Comment: The specific article to the first link (TheTechFAQ) seems dead.

Answer (score 16):

If your browser is pinned to the taskbar you can press Win+Nmbr, where Nmbr is the corresponding number where the icon is in the taskbar.

For example, I have IE on the first position in the taskbar. So when I press Win+1 IE comes up.

Comment: Are you certain this is a standard Windows feature? It does not work on my system (Windows Server 2003), and I did not find it in a list of Windows XP shortcuts on the net.

Comment: It's a standard feature on windows 7. Perhaps Vista. But not Server 2003 or XP.

Comment: its a feature of anyone that has the aero interface. vista, 2008, win7 and 2008 R2.

Comment: Just FYI, if you already have a browser window open it will bring that to the front, instead of opening a new one, when using this shortcut.

Comment: Works great in Windows 11, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will do that nicely. Say for Windows Key + b

```
#b::Run, iexplore.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

Right click your browser shortcut, wherever it is, and choose properties.  Then pick a shortcut key in the "shortcut key" box.  This might start a new instance every time, I'm not sure.

Comment: It does start a new instance, and I think it takes only Ctrl+Alt+Something as a keyboard combination.